# How to create a pipeline from Google Drive to BigQuery

Tags: csv, google-bigquery

I need to do the following:

1. Upload a .csv file to Google Drive
2. Once in the Google Cloud, the file should be opened by a Javascript function stored in Google Storage to apply changes on some columns.
3. The resulting .csv should be used to create a BigQuery table.

This pipeline should be started from desktop command line.

Comment: Have you looked into Cloud Composer? It lets you schedule and compose jobs.

Comment: It is just perfect question for my needs. No need to downvote it.

Comment: I never downvote questions (it looks like you have a good answer now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you directly upload the .csv file in Google Cloud Storage instead of in Google Drive, you can:

1. Trigger a [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/) (which can be automatically triggered when [uploading the file](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background#cloud_storage_example))
2. Perform the edit operation with your JavaScript code inside the Cloud Function.
3. Apply the [node.js client library for BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs) to load the resulting .csv inside the Cloud Function.

You could also create two Cloud Functions to separate their role and create a back-up CSV in GCS following the below steps:

1. Trigger Cloud Function 1.
2. Perform the edit operation with your JavaScript code inside the Cloud Function 1.
3. Save the .csv back in a different bucket in Google Cloud Storage using Cloud Function 1.
4. Trigger Cloud Function 2 to transfer the new .csv to BigQuery (find [here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/master/samples/tables.js#L310) example code).

If you need to first load in Google Drive, have a look on Apps Scripts. You might find a solution [there](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#getting_started).